# Bash script to set env variables does not work when using source and only works with bash -c

Tags: bash, ubuntu, intel-fortran, intel-oneapi

The oneAPI toolkit provided by Intel requires sourcing of a bash script to add several executables/libraries to `$PATH` and other environment variables.
For this, the documentation instructs to run a provided script as

```
source setvars.sh
```

However, on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 system (supported by Intel OneAPI), I get the following error.

```
$ source setvars.sh
  :: ERROR: No env scripts found: No "env/vars.sh" scripts to process.
This can be caused by a bad or incomplete "--config" file.
Can also be caused by an incomplete or missing oneAPI installation.
```

After pouring through forums, I came upon a workaround [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-HPC-Toolkit/How-to-use-zsh-csh-or-tcsh-with-oneAPI-setvars-sh-vars-sh/td-p/1273289) for zsh-type shells.
Following those hints, when I run

```
bash -c 'source setvars.sh'
```

There are no errors reported and the script runs perfectly. As expected, the env variables are not available after execution of the `bash -c`  command.

One workaround to this, is to do

```
bash -c 'source setvars.sh; exec bash'
```

every time I open a new terminal. This is very annoying.

I would like to source `setvars.sh` somewhere inside `.bashrc` or `.profile` and forget about it.

Why does `source setvars.sh` not work and `bash -c 'source setvars.sh'` run without errors here.

Comment: Have you tried `source COMPLETE_PATH/setvars.sh` ?  In seems to be looking in an `env` directory, if you for the entire path it might work?

Comment: What is your shell? The script is for `bash`. There are multiple other shells (`csh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `dash`,...). What shell does your Ubuntu use? You select your preferred shell even on user-level. Different users may use different shells even ona single computer. Some softwares supply a separate configuration script for bash and relsted shellls and a separate one for C shell.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I concur, this is a shell issue. They are probably running under `sh` and not `bash`.

Comment: I've tried using the full path. And I work with a bash shell, the OS is a fresh install. It does seem like a shell issue to me too. I have no idea how to check whether `source` is from a different shell though.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
This turned out to be an issue with the `cd` command being aliased to
`cd "$@" && ls`. Sourcing the `setvars.sh` script before the alias definition solved the issue.

Refer discussion on the Intel Communities forum [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Error-sourcing-setvars-sh-on-Ubuntu-20-04/m-p/1408490).